# Same width and height to html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table td {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-content">
              <table class="table" id="gallery">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div>
                      1
                    </div>
                  </td>                  
                  <td>
                    <div>
                      2
                    </div>
                  </td>                  
                  <td>
                    <div>
                      3
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div>
                     4
                    </div>
                  </td>                  
                  <td>
                    <div>
                     5
                    </div>
                  </td>                  
                  <td>
                    <div>
                      6
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div>
                      7
                    </div>
                  </td>                  
                  <td>
                    <div>
                      8
                    </div>
                  </td>                  
                  <td>
                    <div>
                      9
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>                
              </table>
            </div>
```

I want to create a square layout as below to display some images.

[image]

My HTML for this is as below:

```
    <div class="gallery-content">
      <table class="table" id="gallery">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <img src="../myimage.jpg">
            </div>
          </td>                  
          <td>
            <div>
              <img src="../myimage.jpg">
            </div>
          </td>                  
          <td>
            <div>
              <img src="../myimage.jpg">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>                    
        <tr>....</tr>                    
        <tr>....</tr>                
      </table>
    </div>
```

In this situation, I can not set exact width and height for table cells. That mean width of the `td` is variable.

So here I want to detect that variable width and set it to height using jquery.

I tried it like this, But it doesn't work for me.

```
function windowReszie(){
  var size =$("td").width();
  $("td").height(size);
}

if($('#gallery').length){
  windowReszie()
}
```

Can anybody help me figure this out. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a code snippet?

Comment: @Satpal, Updated my question with a code snippet.

Comment: Why jQuery? There are many ways you could achieve this without any JavaScript at all.

Comment: @jaasum, can we use only CSS for this? 
Here table td width is variable. We don't know what is exact size of the width and we can't use pre define value for width and height in css.

Comment: Meaning, each cell will accept images of the *same unknown* size, or that each cell will receive an image of a *different unknown* size? It's pretty common to allow images to determine the size of a layout in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your `jquery` detect that variable width and set it to `height` when screen resize also

```js
function windowResize(){
  var size =$("td").width();
  $("td").height(size);
}

if($('#gallery').length){
  windowResize();
}

$(window).resize(function(){
  windowResize();
});
```

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table td {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-content">
  <table class="table" id="gallery">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          1
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
          2
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
          3
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>                    
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
         4
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
         5
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
          6
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>                    
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          7
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
          8
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
          9
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>                
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a psuedo element and give it 100% `padding-top` it will be a square:

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table td {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.table td:before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-content">
  <table class="table" id="gallery">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          1
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
          2
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
          3
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>                    
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
         4
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
         5
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
          6
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>                    
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          7
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
          8
        </div>
      </td>                  
      <td>
        <div>
          9
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>                
  </table>
</div>
```